# Calculate logarithm and exponential using simple calculator

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Is there a formula/way how to calculate logarithm precisely like log(3.587) or calculate 5^0.358 just using simple calculator..
I mean calculate precisely like scientific calculator not in estimation result.

Comment: Scientific calculators also give just an approximation.

Comment: As in a calculator that only has +, -, *, /? Do we also have $\sqrt{}$?

Comment: Also have square root.. scientific calculator give exact calculation until at least 10-14 digits.. I mean is there a way calculate like division so we can get answer digit by digit

Answer (score 0):

By adding, subtracting, multiplying and dividing you can calculate exponentials and logarithms with arbitrarily high precision using their respective [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

Unfortunately, you cannot, in general, get a precise decimal expansion of those numbers, as you will very often encounter irrationals!